# Symfony 4 Subscribed Service Injection not found

Tags: symfony

It seems that the method `getSubscribedServices` is not injecting my dependency. When I try to use it with my local alias `registry` it says that the service is not found; would someone have any idea what I am missing ?

```
class UserService implements ServiceSubscriberInterface
{

protected $container;
protected $session;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->session = new Session();
}

public static function getSubscribedServices()
{
    return [
        'registry' => ManagerRegistry::class
    ];
}
```

calling `$this->container->get('registry')` fails with error message

```
You have requested a non-existent service "registry".
```

SERVICES

```
App\Controller\userMgmt\UserService:
    lazy: true

usermgmt:
    alias: App\Controller\userMgmt\UserService
    public: true
```

STACK TRACE

```
     Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
You have requested a non-existent service "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry".

at vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php:274
at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->make('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\ManagerRegistry', 1)
 (vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php:222)
at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\ManagerRegistry')
 (src/Controller/userMgmt/UserService.php:52)
at App\Controller\userMgmt\UserService->getPrivileges()
 (var/cache/dev/ContainerVwU8dOz/UserService_3c10c57.php:40)
at UserService_3c10c57->getPrivileges()
 (src/Controller/userMgmt/UserMgmtController.php:81)
at App\Controller\userMgmt\UserMgmtController->userLogin(object(Request), object(UserRepository))
 (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:149)
at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
 (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66)
at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
 (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:188)
at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
 (public/index.php:37)
```

Comment: do you remember to mark service as public?

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete stack trace for this error?

Comment: @JanGaltowski I updated question with `service.yaml`, as you can see it is public ?

Comment: @xabbuh I updated with complete stack trace

Comment: The error is now a bit different. The container is not complaining about the missing `registry` service, but refers to the missing `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry` service. There is no alias for this class name registered by default. I think you want to update the service subscriber to use either `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry` or `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface` instead.

Comment: tried both suggestions and getting similar error with both `The "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.`

Comment: It does not do much good to define UserService as public.  It is ManagerRegistry that needs to be public.  However, using the subscriber interface should take care of that for you.

Comment: @Cerad I need to define it as public to be able to call it from the container ?

Comment: Nope.  The subscriber interface should take care of that.  I can't tell what is wrong but you have something else going on.  Maybe start with an empty class and do nothing but try to get the registry.

Comment: So you think the code is correct in principle ? (asking because that is the first time I am doing this). Because if the code is correct and given I provided the stack trace; could that be a bug ? btw I also tried with public false

Comment: It is not a bug.  The error is probably coming from something else completely.    For example you have case issues in your usermgt service definition.  And there is probably no reason to define a usermgt service anyways.  So once again, start with a clean project and do nothing but get the registry working in your UserService.